# How do I count the number of duplicate groups of data after using groupby in pandas with python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Here is what I did:

1. Imported CSV File.
2. Converted to dataframe with 4 columns I wanted.
3. Used groupby to group by ID.

Now I have an object where I have:

> ID # associated with a 3 column dataframe

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('chim_work.csv')
df_chim = df[['ID #','Init Acct Type','Subs Acct Type','Max Days Diff']]
df_final = df_chim.dropna()
df_grouped = df_final.groupby('ID #')

for i, d in df_grouped:
    dfn = d.drop(columns=['ID #'])
    print(i)
    print(dfn)
```

So I printed out in a `for` loop and it gives ID# with a 3 column dataframe for each loop.

I want to figure out which of these resulting grouped dataframes are duplicates, how many duplicates exist, and the ID#s of the duplicates. The entire dataframe associated with a given ID# has to be identical to another dataframe with a different ID#.

So I would like to return:

> A --> 102, 109, 130 --> 3

(which tells me id# 102, 109, and 130 are identical, there are three of them and we call this group A).

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by ID gives you the data corresponding to every unique ID, but it sounds like you want the IDs corresponding to each unique set of data.

It seems like you might want to groupby everything except ID.

You could try

```
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(df_final.groupby(['Init Acct Type','Subs Acct Type','Max Days Diff'])['ID #'].apply(list))
```

That would give you a dataframe each set of unique data is in a row and the 'ID' column holds a list of the corresponding IDs.

Then count the number of IDs in each group

```
df_grouped['count'] = df_grouped.apply(lambda row: len(row['ID #']), axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried your code exactly. Wasn't sure how to print it but I printed df_crouped['count'] got not errors and the output was not what I was looking for. Is there anyway you would be willing to help me a little more?